# Android Mosquitto - Client connection state

Tags: android, mqtt, mosquitto

I've a MQTT client runnning in Android, and a MQTT Broker in the server. My problem is where we will use the app we have some connections drop so my web app needs to know the current state of the client.

So what we are doing right now is: 
1 - The server sends a random number to the clients (each client will receive a different random number)
2 - The android client receives the number and send to a web service
3 - The web service writes in SQL db
4 - The server wait 4 secs to the response from android client and if the random number sent by the server == to the number in the db , the client is connected.

But now the problem is when, multi-users sends the random number the only one that will be write in the db is the last one so it's huge design fault.

In order to fix the only good solution is to get a direct response from the MQTT client and have to be unique per client but i don't know if is possible or if is the best way to go.

Some draw to better understand:
[Flow](https://docs.google.com/drawings/d/1OyudifE93GgqP0VF_vfFhuWBmqdHO0Mh79K6J7U5Vxk/edit?usp=sharing)

Here is my android code:

```
public class MQTTService extends Service implements MqttCallback {

public static final String DEBUG_TAG = "MqttService"; // Debug TAG

private static final String MQTT_THREAD_NAME = "MqttService[" + DEBUG_TAG + "]"; // Handler
                                                                                    // Thread
                                                                                    // ID

private String MQTT_BROKER = ""; // Broker URL
                                    // or IP
                                    // Address
private static final int MQTT_PORT = 1883; // Broker Port

public static final int MQTT_QOS_0 = 0; // QOS Level 0 ( Delivery Once no
                                        // confirmation )
public static final int MQTT_QOS_1 = 1; // QOS Level 1 ( Delivery at least
                                        // Once with confirmation )
public static final int MQTT_QOS_2 = 2; // QOS Level 2 ( Delivery only once
                                        // with confirmation with handshake
                                        // )

private static final int MQTT_KEEP_ALIVE = 30000; // KeepAlive Interval in
                                                    // MS
private static final String MQTT_KEEP_ALIVE_TOPIC_FORMAT = "/users/%s/keepalive"; // Topic
                                                                                    // format
                                                                                    // for
                                                                                    // KeepAlives
private static final byte[] MQTT_KEEP_ALIVE_MESSAGE = { 0 }; // Keep Alive
                                                                // message
                                                                // to send
private static final int MQTT_KEEP_ALIVE_QOS = MQTT_QOS_2; // Default
                                                            // Keepalive QOS

private static final boolean MQTT_CLEAN_SESSION = false; // Start a clean
                                                            // session?

private static final String MQTT_URL_FORMAT = "tcp://%s:%d"; // URL Format
                                                                // normally
                                                                // don't
                                                                // change

public static final String ACTION_START = DEBUG_TAG + ".START"; // Action
                                                                // to
                                                                // start
public static final String ACTION_STOP = DEBUG_TAG + ".STOP"; // Action to
                                                                // stop
public static final String ACTION_KEEPALIVE = DEBUG_TAG + ".KEEPALIVE"; // Action
                                                                        // to
                                                                        // keep
                                                                        // alive
                                                                        // used
                                                                        // by
                                                                        // alarm
                                                                        // manager
private static final String ACTION_RECONNECT = DEBUG_TAG + ".RECONNECT"; // Action
                                                                            // to
                                                                            // reconnect

// private final String DEVICE_ID_FORMAT = "andr_%s"; // Device ID
// Format, add
// any prefix
// you'd like
// Note: There
// is a 23
// character
// limit you
// will get
// An NPE if you
// go over that
// limit
private boolean mStarted = false; // Is the Client started?
private String user_ID; // Device ID, Secure.ANDROID_ID
private Handler mConnHandler; // Seperate Handler thread for networking

private MqttDefaultFilePersistence mDataStore; // Defaults to FileStore
private MemoryPersistence mMemStore; // On Fail reverts to MemoryStore
private MqttConnectOptions mOpts; // Connection Options

private MqttTopic mKeepAliveTopic; // Instance Variable for Keepalive topic

private MqttClient mClient; // Mqtt Client

private AlarmManager mAlarmManager; // Alarm manager to perform repeating
                                    // tasks
private ConnectivityManager mConnectivityManager; // To check for
                                                    // connectivity changes

public static final String TAG_CONNECTED = "CONNECTED";
public static final String TAG_ASSIGNED = "ASSIGNED";
public static final String TAG_REFRESH = "REFRESH";

public String TOPIC_CONNECTED = null;
public String TOPIC_ASSIGNED = null;
public String TOPIC_REFRESH = null;

private Intent intent;

private PendingIntent alarmIntent;

private AppMaintenance appStatus;

/**
 * Initializes the DeviceId and most instance variables Including the
 * Connection Handler, Datastore, Alarm Manager and ConnectivityManager.
 */
@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();

    // mDeviceId = String.format(DEVICE_ID_FORMAT,
    // Secure.getString(getContentResolver(), Secure.ANDROID_ID));

    android.os.Debug.waitForDebugger(); // Debugger
    appStatus = (AppMaintenance) getApplicationContext();

    ExceptionHandler.register(this, appStatus.getException_URL());

    HandlerThread thread = new HandlerThread(MQTT_THREAD_NAME);
    thread.start();

    mConnHandler = new Handler(thread.getLooper());

    try {
        mDataStore = new MqttDefaultFilePersistence(getCacheDir().getAbsolutePath());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // writeToFile("Exception - onCreate()");
        e.printStackTrace();
        mDataStore = null;
        mMemStore = new MemoryPersistence();
    }

    mOpts = new MqttConnectOptions();
    mOpts.setCleanSession(MQTT_CLEAN_SESSION);
    // Do not set keep alive interval on mOpts we keep track of it with
    // alarm's

    mAlarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
    mConnectivityManager = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    registerReceiver(mConnectivityReceiver, new IntentFilter(ConnectivityManager.CONNECTIVITY_ACTION));
}

/**
 * Start MQTT Client
 * 
 * @param Context
 *            context to start the service with
 * @return void
 */
public static void actionStart(Context ctx) {
    Intent i = new Intent(ctx, MQTTService.class);
    i.setAction(ACTION_START);
    ctx.startService(i);
}

/**
 * Stop MQTT Client
 * 
 * @param Context
 *            context to start the service with
 * @return void
 */
public static void actionStop(Context ctx) {
    Intent i = new Intent(ctx, MQTTService.class);
    i.setAction(ACTION_STOP);
    ctx.startService(i);
}

/**
 * Send a KeepAlive Message
 * 
 * @param Context
 *            context to start the service with
 * @return void
 */
public static void actionKeepalive(Context ctx) {
    Intent i = new Intent(ctx, MQTTService.class);
    i.setAction(ACTION_KEEPALIVE);
    ctx.startService(i);
}

/**
 * Service onStartCommand Handles the action passed via the Intent
 * 
 * @return START_REDELIVER_INTENT
 */
@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);

    this.intent = intent;

    SharedPreferences myPrefs = getSharedPreferences("UserPreferences", MODE_PRIVATE);
    MQTT_BROKER = myPrefs.getString("broker", "");
    user_ID = myPrefs.getString("userID", "");

    String action = intent.getAction();

    TOPIC_CONNECTED = user_ID + "\\" + TAG_CONNECTED;
    TOPIC_ASSIGNED = user_ID + "\\" + TAG_ASSIGNED;
    TOPIC_REFRESH = user_ID + "\\" + TAG_REFRESH;

    Log.i(DEBUG_TAG, "Received action of " + action);
    // writeToFile("Received action of " + action);
    if (user_ID.isEmpty() || user_ID == null)
        action = null;

    if (action == null) {
        Log.i(DEBUG_TAG, "Starting service with no action\n Probably from a crash");
        // writeToFile("Starting service with no action\n Probably from a crash");
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), getString(R.string.mqtt_warning_userid), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        action = null;
    } else {
        if (action.equals(ACTION_START)) {
            Log.i(DEBUG_TAG, "Received ACTION_START");
            // writeToFile("Received ACTION_START");
            start();
        } else if (action.equals(ACTION_STOP)) {
            Log.i(DEBUG_TAG, "Received ACTION_STOP");
            // writeToFile("Received ACTION_STOP");
            stop();
        } else if (action.equals(ACTION_KEEPALIVE)) {
            Log.i(DEBUG_TAG, "Received ACTION_KEEPALIVE");
            // writeToFile("Received ACTION_KEEPALIVE");
            keepAlive();
        } else if (action.equals(ACTION_RECONNECT)) {
            Log.i(DEBUG_TAG, "Received ACTION_RECONNECT");
            // writeToFile("Received ACTION_RECONNECT");
            reconnectIfNecessary();
        }
    }

    return START_NOT_STICKY;
}

/**
 * Attempts connect to the Mqtt Broker and listen for Connectivity changes
 * via ConnectivityManager.CONNECTVITIY_ACTION BroadcastReceiver
 */
private synchronized void start() {
    if (mStarted) {
        Log.i(DEBUG_TAG, "Attempt to start while already started");
        // writeToFile("Attempt to start while already started");
        return;
    }

    if (hasScheduledKeepAlives()) {
        stopKeepAlives();
    }

    connect();
}

/**
 * Attempts to stop the Mqtt client as well as halting all keep alive
 * messages queued in the alarm manager
 */
private synchronized void stop() {
    if (!mStarted) {
        Log.i(DEBUG_TAG, "Attemt to stop connection that isn't running");
        // writeToFile("Attemt to stop connection that isn't running");
        return;
    }

    if (mClient != null) {
        mConnHandler.post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    mClient.disconnect();
                } catch (Exception ex) {
                    // writeToFile("Exception - stop() ");
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                    mClient = null;
                    mStarted = false;
                } finally {
                    mClient = null;
                    mStarted = false;
                    stopKeepAlives();
                }
            }
        });
    }
}

/**
 * Connects to the broker with the appropriate datastore
 */
private synchronized void connect() {
    String url = String.format(Locale.US, MQTT_URL_FORMAT, MQTT_BROKER, MQTT_PORT);
    Log.i(DEBUG_TAG, "Connecting with URL: " + url);
    // writeToFile("Connecting with URL: " + url);
    try {
        if (mDataStore != null) {
            Log.i(DEBUG_TAG, "Connecting with DataStore");
            // writeToFile("Connecting with DataStore");
            mClient = new MqttClient(url, user_ID, mDataStore);
        } else {
            Log.i(DEBUG_TAG, "Connecting with MemStore");
            // writeToFile("Connecting with MemStore");
            mClient = new MqttClient(url, user_ID, mMemStore);
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // writeToFile("Exception - connect L.343");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    mConnHandler.post(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {

                mClient.connect(mOpts);

                mClient.subscribe(new String[] { TOPIC_CONNECTED, TOPIC_ASSIGNED, TOPIC_REFRESH }, new int[] { MQTT_QOS_0,
                        MQTT_KEEP_ALIVE_QOS, MQTT_KEEP_ALIVE_QOS });

                mClient.setCallback(new MQTTPushCallback(MQTTService.this, intent, user_ID, TOPIC_CONNECTED, TOPIC_ASSIGNED,
                        TOPIC_REFRESH));

                mStarted = true; // Service is now connected

                Log.i(DEBUG_TAG, "Successfully connected and subscribed starting keep alives");
                // writeToFile("Successfully connected and subscribed starting keep alives");
                startKeepAlives();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                // writeToFile("Exception - connect L.366");
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
}

/**
 * Schedules keep alives via a PendingIntent in the Alarm Manager
 */
private void startKeepAlives() {
    Intent i = new Intent();
    i.setClass(this, MQTTService.class);
    i.setAction(ACTION_KEEPALIVE);
    alarmIntent = PendingIntent.getService(this, 0, i, 0);
    mAlarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, System.currentTimeMillis() + MQTT_KEEP_ALIVE, MQTT_KEEP_ALIVE, alarmIntent);
    Log.i(DEBUG_TAG, "Started keepAlives sucessfully");
    // writeToFile("Started keepAlives sucessfully");
}

/**
 * Cancels the Pending Intent in the alarm manager
 */
private void stopKeepAlives() {
    if (mAlarmManager != null) {
        mAlarmManager.cancel(alarmIntent);
    }
}

/**
 * Publishes a KeepALive to the topic in the broker
 */
private synchronized void keepAlive() {
    // if (isForeground()) {
    if (isConnected()) {
        try {
            sendKeepAlive();
            return;
        } catch (MqttConnectivityException ex) {
            // writeToFile("Exception - KeepAlive() 1");
            ex.printStackTrace();
            reconnectIfNecessary();
        } catch (MqttPersistenceException ex) {
            // writeToFile("Exception - KeepAlive() 2");
            ex.printStackTrace();
            stop();
            restartService();

        } catch (MqttException ex) {
            // writeToFile("Exception - KeepAlive() 3");
            ex.printStackTrace();
            stop();
            restartService();

        } catch (Exception ex) {
            // writeToFile("Exception - KeepAlive() 4");
            ex.printStackTrace();
            stop();
            restartService();
        }
    }
}

/**
 * Checks the current connectivity and reconnects if it is required.
 */
private synchronized void reconnectIfNecessary() {
    if (!mStarted && mClient == null)
        start();
}

/**
 * Query's the NetworkInfo via ConnectivityManager to return the current
 * connected state
 * 
 * @return boolean true if we are connected false otherwise
 */
private boolean isNetworkAvailable() {
    NetworkInfo info = mConnectivityManager.getActiveNetworkInfo();
    return info == null ? false : info.isConnected();
}

/**
 * Verifies the client State with our local connected state
 * 
 * @return true if its a match we are connected false if we aren't connected
 */
private boolean isConnected() {
    if (mStarted && mClient != null && !mClient.isConnected()) {
        Log.i(DEBUG_TAG, "Mismatch between what we think is connected and what is connected");
        // writeToFile("Mismatch between what we think is connected and what is connected");
    }

    if (mClient != null) {
        return mStarted && mClient.isConnected() ? true : false;
    }

    return false;
}

/**
 * Receiver that listens for connectivity changes via ConnectivityManager
 */
private final BroadcastReceiver mConnectivityReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        // writeToFile("isNetworkAvailable = " + isNetworkAvailable());
        if (isNetworkAvailable() && !mStarted) {
            Log.i(DEBUG_TAG, "Connectivity Changed...");
            // Intent i = new Intent(context, MQTTService.class);
            // i.setAction(ACTION_RECONNECT);
            // context.startService(i);
            restartService();
        } else if (!isNetworkAvailable()) {
            stop();
        }
    }

};

/**
 * Sends a Keep Alive message to the specified topic
 * 
 * @see MQTT_KEEP_ALIVE_MESSAGE
 * @see MQTT_KEEP_ALIVE_TOPIC_FORMAT
 * @return MqttDeliveryToken specified token you can choose to wait for
 *         completion
 */
private synchronized MqttDeliveryToken sendKeepAlive() throws MqttConnectivityException, MqttPersistenceException, MqttException {
    if (!isConnected())
        throw new MqttConnectivityException();

    if (mKeepAliveTopic == null) {
        mKeepAliveTopic = mClient.getTopic(String.format(Locale.US, MQTT_KEEP_ALIVE_TOPIC_FORMAT, user_ID));
    }

    Log.i(DEBUG_TAG, "Sending Keepalive to " + MQTT_BROKER);
    // writeToFile("Sending Keepalive to " + MQTT_BROKER);

    MqttMessage message = new MqttMessage(MQTT_KEEP_ALIVE_MESSAGE);
    message.setQos(MQTT_KEEP_ALIVE_QOS);

    return mKeepAliveTopic.publish(message);
}

/**
 * Query's the AlarmManager to check if there is a keep alive currently
 * scheduled
 * 
 * @return true if there is currently one scheduled false otherwise
 */
private synchronized boolean hasScheduledKeepAlives() {
    Intent i = new Intent();
    i.setClass(this, MQTTService.class);
    i.setAction(ACTION_KEEPALIVE);
    PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, i, PendingIntent.FLAG_NO_CREATE);

    return pi != null ? true : false;
}

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {
    return null;
}

/**
 * Connectivity Lost from broker
 */
@Override
public void connectionLost(Throwable arg0) {
    stopKeepAlives();

    mClient = null;

    if (isNetworkAvailable()) {
        reconnectIfNecessary();
    }
}

/**
 * Publish Message Completion
 */
@Override
public void deliveryComplete(IMqttDeliveryToken arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

/**
 * Received Message from broker
 */
@Override
public void messageArrived(String arg0, MqttMessage arg1) throws Exception {
    // Log.i(DEBUG_TAG,
    // "  Topic:\t" + topic.getName() + "  Message:\t"
    // + new String(message.getPayload()) + "  QoS:\t"
    // + message.getQos());

}

/**
 * MqttConnectivityException Exception class
 */
private class MqttConnectivityException extends Exception {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -7385866796799469420L;
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    try {
        mClient.unsubscribe(new String[] { TOPIC_CONNECTED, TOPIC_ASSIGNED, TOPIC_REFRESH });
        mClient.disconnect(0);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        // writeToFile("Exception - onDestroy() 1");
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        new WS_LOGOUT(this).execute(user_ID);
    }
}

public void restartService() {
    mKeepAliveTopic = null;
    actionStart(getApplicationContext()); // restart the service
}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

What sort of latency can you live with when knowing if the client is disconnected?

You can use the Last Will and Testament feature to publish a value to a topic when the server detects that the MQTT keep alive time has expired with out receiving a ping from the client.

You can set the keep alive time at connection time. But depending on your requirements (battery/network usage) you need to work out what to set it to. If I remember correctly the default is 30 seconds (might be 60)

When your client connects it can set a flag on a persitent topic to say it's online, and the LWT can set this to 0.

e.g.

on connect publish "1" to client/[uniqueid]/online

set the LWT to publish "0" to client/[uniqueid]/online

Comment: I want to use the keep alive time, if the client doesn't say nothing (doesn't send a keepAlive) i assume is dead.

Comment: I want to use the keep alive time, if the client doesn't say nothing (doesn't send a keepAlive) i assume is dead. i'am using a 30 secs interval between keep alives. I understand the concept but i need to get the information on my server who is connected in the last 30 secs, so the broker save that info in some location so i can reach?! thanks in advance

Comment: You don't have to publish "1" to the online topic, you could publish a timestamp, this would let you know when a client came online. Then use the LWT to set this to 0.